# Can you convert a Django 'DateField()' to 'date'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I was using the 'DateField()' in Django, and I wanted to find the time between two dates that are stored in the 'DateField()' field. How can I do this?

This is what I was trying originally: `length = datetime.timedelta(start, end)`

It gives me this error: `TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: DateField`

Answer (score 1):

The Django `DateField` represents dates as `datetime.date` objects. You can get the `timedelta` by using regular arithmetic operators: `difference = end-start`. That will give you a [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), and you can access the `days` member of that to see how many days are between `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can use the `date` filter: `{{datetime|date:"d m Y" }}` in your template.

That will return a 'dd mm yyyy' formated date.

Comment: So how would I plug that into this field:
```start = models.DateField()```

Comment: @Kool
in the views.py
`def yourView(request):
 Data = myModels.objects.all()
 return render(request, template_name, {"data":Data})`

and in your template :
`<p>{{data.start|date"d f y"}}</p>`

Comment: While you answer is technically correct, it does not answer OP's question. OP is asking how to calculate the difference between two days in normal Python code, not in a template.